# Finite free resolutions of modules over coordinate ring of smooth elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, elliptic-curves, localization

I believed for a while that the reason you can't find a finite free resolution (with the free modules finitely generated) of $(x - 1, y - 1)$ as a module over $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(y^2 - x^3)$ is that $y^2 = x^3$ isn't smooth.

I thought the singularity created "noise," so that you must localise at $(x - 1, y - 1),$ allowing you to find a finite projective resolution.

Then I tried to find a finite free (finitely generated) resolution of $(x + 1, y)$ as a module over $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(y^2 - (x^3 + 1))$ and couldn't, despite this being the coordinate ring of a smooth elliptic curve.

So when can we find finite free (finitely generated) resolutions over smooth elliptic curves?
Furthermore, if I'm right that $(x + 1, y)$ has no finite free (finitely generated) resolution, can I get any intuition as to why?

Comment: In general, free resolutions are guaranteed to exist only locally. You may want to consider a projective resolution instead. In both examples, you have non-singular points, so locally you will have a free resolution of length $0$. This follows from the fact that locally the ideal is generated by a single element and free. In the second example, I believe that one can construct a projective resolution of length at most $1$, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Youngsu I'm aware of these points. I want to know if there's any way to predict when we can get a free resolution in a situation where free =/= projective - e.g., without localising. Maybe I just shouldn't have assumed this has any relationship to smoothness.